# How to perform SQL like "IN" query using Salat for mongodb?

Tags: scala, mongodb, salat

I have many records with below structure saved in mongodb.

```
case class User(_id:ObjectId = new ObjectId, email:String, role:String, employeeID:Int, createdOn:DateTime)
```

How can I execute the "IN" like query on mongodb using salat?

e.g.

```
val data = UserDAO.find(MongoDbObject("employeeID" -> List(2,4,5)) // (NOT working)
```

Thanks
Pawan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Casbah DSL:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.query.Imports._

val data = UserDAO.find("employeeID" $in List(2,4,5))
```